# [Android]Use the Google Drive Sdk, how to sign in to another account

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I follow the tutorial.

[Google Drive Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java)

```
                if (accountName != null) {

                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();

                }
```

but only device account:

ex) `email : xxx@xxx.com`

How do I access the other account?

ex) `email : xxxx@xxx.com, password : ******`

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here what is being done through REST API to Add New Account.
I'll be explainging with a generalized code .

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(YourActivity.this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

                                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

Then in **OnActivityResult** Hanlde ***REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER***

```
 case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(android.accounts.AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);


            }
            break;
```

android.accounts.AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME this will give the Account Name in a dailog and add account option below which will add up a new account.

hope it may help you.